# Relations on equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

To be short, I will abstract a bit from my particular problem.

Let $S$ be a set and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation, defined on that set. Let $R \subseteq (S/\sim) \times (S/\sim)$ be a relation defined on the quotient set $S/\sim$. Let $L \subseteq S$. Can $L$ be closed under $R$? What confuses me here is that $R$ relates an equivalence class to an equivalence class, while $L$ is not an equivalence class.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Don't you mean $R\subseteq (S/\sim)\times(S/\sim)$ here?

Comment: This is probably just some abuse of notation. Probably we look at the image of $L$ inside $S/\sim$, i.e., consider $L_\sim=\left\{[x]:x\in L\right\}$, and then state that $L_\sim$ is closed under $R$.